# To use python pickle or not?

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I am playing around with Python for the first time and have a mini project on my hand that I am toying with to get a grasp on this language. I am basically interested in knowing if I am conjuring up a good solution or if there are better ways to go about doing it.

There is a CSV file which basically lists out integers (or should list out integers) with about three integers per row separated by commas. My way of doing this is to :

1. read each line into a variable using readline()
2. split the variable by specifying comma as the delimiter
3. once the variable is split, I access each element of this size 3 array and do a test which checks if it is an integer or some other data type

This is pretty straight forward and technically, 'does the job'. However, my mind is in conflict after I read some of the Python documentation that suggests the use of a pickle module to read a file consisting of integers.

[links to the Python documentatio](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Apparently, each line is read in as a string if readline is being read. And this means, integers are being read in as strings as well and there might be a loss of precision here? Pickle, is a magic module that converts everything into it's string representation and then it can be unconverted back to it's original data type representation without losing precision.

IMHO, my program code works fine without the use of the pickle module, but in quest of writing good code, what do you guys suggest and what is your rationale behind it:

Answer (score 7):

`pickle` expects the file to be in a specific format, generated by the `pickle` module itself. For reading CSV files you should use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module instead.

Also, Python supports arbitrary-length integers, so there's no need to worry about them being strings; once they are converted you will get every last digit.

```
>>> int('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890')
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890L
```

Answer (score 4):

If you read the documentation for the [`pickle` module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), the first paragraph sums up the purpose of the module pretty well:

> The `pickle` module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure.

`pickle` is intended, for the most part, to dump Python objects into files and read them back again.

As for precision, both CSV and Python pickle files are storing data as strings, so there is no loss of precision.

Personally, I would not use pickle. It prevents your simple data from being read by other programs and edited with a graphical editor. If you had complicated dictionaries and other Python objects to worry about, pickle would be a good storage method. In this case, however, it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on where you file of integers is coming from and if you want it created / edited from other sources.

Pickle can store/retrieve python structures but its not good for interchanging data from other systems and possibly even python versions.